# How to read csv with double quotes from WoS?

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read CSV files from the citation report of Web of Science. This is the structure of the file:

```
TI=clinical case of cognitive dysfunction syndrome AND CU=MEXICO
null
Timespan=All years. Indexes=SCI-EXPANDED, SSCI, A&HCI, ESCI.

"Title","Authors","Corporate Authors","Editors","Book Editors","Source Title","Publication Date","Publication Year","Volume","Issue","Part Number","Supplement","Special Issue","Beginning Page","Ending Page","Article Number","DOI","Conference Title","Conference Date","Total Citations","Average per Year","1988","1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016"
""Didy," a clinical case of cognitive dysfunction syndrome","Heiblum, Moises; Labastida, Rocio; Chavez Gris, Gilberto; Tejeda, Alberto","","","","JOURNAL OF VETERINARY BEHAVIOR-CLINICAL APPLICATIONS AND RESEARCH","MAY-JUN 2007","2007","2","3","","","","68","72","","10.1016/j.jveb.2007.05.002","","","2","0.20","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0"
""Didy," a clinical case of cognitive dysfunction syndrome (vol 2, pg 68, 2007)","Heiblum, A.; Labastida, R.; Gris, Chavez G.; Tejeda, A.; Edwards, Claudia","","","","JOURNAL OF VETERINARY BEHAVIOR-CLINICAL APPLICATIONS AND RESEARCH","SEP-OCT 2007","2007","2","5","","","","183","183","","","","","0","0.00","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"
```

I manage to import the it using `fread`, however, I still want to know which is the appropriate `quote` and why is assigning **"Didy,"** as row names despite that the argument is `NULL`. This are the arguments that I'm using.

```
s_file <- read.csv(savedrecs.txt, 
                   skip = 4, 
                   header = TRUE,                            
                   row.names = NULL,
                   quote = '\"',
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is not a valid csv file format. There are some double double quotes (i.e. "") without a comma. For example there is one at the beginning of the second line.

```
""Didy," a clinical case of cognitive dysfunction syndrome", etc.
```

So it thinks there is a null followed by `Diddy,` followed by `" a clinical case of cognitive dysfunction syndrome"` Fix up the file and you should be ok. E.g. the second line should start with

```
"","Didy","a clinical case of cognitive dysfunction syndrome"
```

Comment: I don't think your parsing of the data lines is correct. I think the full "Title" is `"'Didy,' a clinical case of cognitive dysfunction syndrome"`.